# How to read a shape(.shp) file and display its values USING JAVA CODE

Tags: java, postgresql, coordinates, shapefile

I have a shape file like below. I converted it using an online converter. then I am getting values of this file as below

[image]

> {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[973154.7117999941,194614.3315999955],[973733.1576000005,194006.27879999578],[973685.9174000025,193958.0421999991],[973648.6635999978,193712.4756000042],[973648.052399993,193711.8941999972],[973525.3418000042,193713.4443999976],[973489.2430000007,193713.75579999387],[973434.6291999966,193713.75579999387],[973338.1589999944,193619.1521999985],[973282.610799998,193672.8328000009],[973265.806400001,193687.9265999943],[973246.2016000003,193707.22059999406],[973221.9282000065,193730.8708000034],[973190.808799997,193761.98980000615],[973150.0426000059,193801.5124000013],[973064.4640000015,193885.53419999778],[973003.7818000019,193945.2828000039],[973005.9601999968,193949.0175999999],[972911.9798000008,194040.50859999657],[972812.7090000063,194138.84540000558],[972728.6863999963,194053.8897999972],[972671.7383999974,193996.00779999793],[972693.9886000007,193973.4458000064],[972697.2559999973,193970.17900000513],[973180.8501999974,193471.33599999547],[973178.9834000021,193469.46819999814],[973156.2663999945,193449.7080000043],[973078.4679999948,193380.77760000527],[972940.6092000008,193251.3222000003],[972792.1697999984,193107.86200000346],[972726.1974000037,193043.75599999726],[972696.9449999928,193014.815200001],[972695.0771999955,193016.37060000002],[972499.9596000016,193216.46819999814],[972248.2037999928,193474.13639999926],[972136.7970000058,193588.03319999576],[972147.6886000037,193598.30220000446],[972141.7758000046,193603.90420000255],[972405.9792000055,193869.9740000069],[972333.1604000032,193941.5488000065],[972499.9596000016,194116.7502000034],[972676.0841999948,194301.77220000327],[972860.2456,194476.96639999747],[972904.5110000074,194434.79039999843],[972936.5644000024,194403.67139999568],[972963.7939999998,194430.27779999375],[973154.7117999941,194614.3315999955]]]}

this is one row of data. like this I have 46823 data. I want to store this data to my postgresql table. my table is geometries and it has 2 columns 'name','geom'. My table syntax is given below.

> CREATE TABLE geometries (name varchar, geom geometry);

I wrote java code to read .shp file.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.nocrala.tools.gis.data.esri.shapefile.ShapeFileReader;
import org.nocrala.tools.gis.data.esri.shapefile.ValidationPreferences;
import org.nocrala.tools.gis.data.esri.shapefile.exception.InvalidShapeFileException;
import org.nocrala.tools.gis.data.esri.shapefile.header.ShapeFileHeader;
import org.nocrala.tools.gis.data.esri.shapefile.shape.AbstractShape;
public class BigFileExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
      InvalidShapeFileException {

    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(
        "D:\\Test\\Filename.shp");
     ValidationPreferences prefs = new ValidationPreferences();
    prefs.setMaxNumberOfPointsPerShape(16650);
    ShapeFileReader r = new ShapeFileReader(is, prefs);

    ShapeFileHeader h = r.getHeader();
    System.out.println("The shape type of this files is " + h.getShapeType());

    int total = 0;
    AbstractShape s;
    while ((s = r.next()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s.getShapeType());

      total++;
    }
    System.out.println("Total shapes read: " + total);
    is.close();
  }}
```

After executing this code i am getting only the shape as 'POLYGON'. In my shape file there is some multipolygon also. But my code did not give me such output.
Also how do I get the coordinate values? what should I write to get the coordinates in the shape file? Please help me to get this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer for my question. I just ignored the above mentioned code and I used geotool maven dependency for the purpose. Please refer below link

First go through this link

http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/data/shape.html

After the above link please refer the below link

http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/data/shape.html

You can definitely find out the solution. :-) if you have any queries regarding this I will here to help u.. Thanks

Comment: Do you know where the DataStore class is？I can't import it.

Comment: Dependency in the example is invalid. Here is what you need to do (gradle):
`repositories {
        maven { url "http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/"}
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.geotools:gt-shapefile:19.4'
    }`